# How to get last edited post of every user in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have user data in two tables like

```
1. USERID | USERPOSTID

2. USERPOSTID | USERPOST | LAST_EDIT_TIME
```

How do I get the last edited post and its time for *every* user? Assume that every user has 5 posts, and each one is edited at least once.

Will I have to write a loop iterating over every user, find the USERPOST with MAX(LAST_EDIT_TIME) and then collect the values? I tried GROUP BY, but I can't put USERPOSTID or USERPOST in an aggregate function. TIA.

Comment: Look at the [`distinct on` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

Comment: @Abelisto this worked for me! If you want to submit a slightly more detailed answer I could mark yours as accepted.

Comment: I just pointed to the documentation. Everything other you did yourself ;) Just remember that `distinct on` returns only one row for each group even if there are several rows with the same maximum `LAST_EDIT_TIME` values. In that case the [Andreas's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42961555/593144) looks more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like something like this should work:

```
create table users(
id serial primary key,
username varchar(50)
);

create table posts(
id serial primary key,
userid integer references users(id),
post_text text,
update_date timestamp default current_timestamp
);

insert into users(username)values('Kalpit');
insert into posts(userid,post_text)values(1,'first test');
insert into posts(userid,post_text)values(1,'second test');


select  *
from    users u
join    posts p on p.userid = u.id
where   p.update_date =
    ( select max( update_date )
        from    posts 
        where   userid = u.id )
```

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4b240/4/0

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [windowing function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-window.html) here:

```
select 
    USERID
    , USERPOSTID
from 
    USERS
    left join (
        select 
            USERID
            , row_number() over (
                partition by USERID
                order by LAST_EDIT_TIME desc) row_num
        from 
            USERPOST
    ) most_recent
    on most_recent.USERID = USERS.USERID
    and row_num = 1
```